# Where to pursue a PhD in history of mathematics in Europe?

Tags: reference-request

This is more a soft question, and I am not sure where I should place it so I ask for excuses if this is not the right place, but I could not find any other that seemed more suitable.

I would like to know which Universities in Europe are as of 2020 having or offering a PhD in history of mathematics. Of course, I do not expect a full list but at least a list of some Math Departments having a certain "tradition" on the subject.

Also, I do not know what skills (at any level) are desirable to study History of Mathematics (speaking/understanding several different languages is something useful? what about knowing latin or greek?).

Thanks advance.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I would also like to see answers for N America as well:-)

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want the Ph.D. to be based in a mathematics department rather than (say) a history and philosophy of science department?

Comment: No, your observation is actually very accurate. It seems that I "automatically" thought that one should look only at maths departments instead of philosophy or history. In any case if someone has an insightful knowledge of Universities or Dependences (to be even more general) where such a PhD can be done, please leave it as an answer or comment :)

Answer (score 8):

According to the Mathematics Genealogy Project (https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/search.php) database, the following universities have awarded three or more mathematics PhDs for dissertations with a history subject classification since 2000:

**Germany**

Bergische Universität Wuppertal

Friedrich-Schiller-Universität Jena

Ludwig-Maximilians-Universität München

Martin-Luther-Universität Halle-Wittenberg

Philipps-Universität Marburg

Technische Universität Berlin

Universität Hamburg

Universität Stuttgart

**France**

Université Paris Diderot - Paris 7

Université Pierre-et-Marie-Curie - Paris VI

**Netherlands**

Universiteit Utrecht

Universiteit van Amsterdam

**UK**

The Open University

University of St. Andrews

**US**

Brown University

Harvard University

The Johns Hopkins University

**Brazil**

Universidade Federal do Espírito Santo

Comment: Thanks for your answer Viktor. As an accomplised researcher on History of Mathematics could you please give us more insight on what skills are desirable?

Comment: @Luis Hard to say anything in general. There is no universal methodology or skillset. It depends on the project what specific mathematical/linguistic/historical/philosophical/etc. knowledge is needed.